# Sending HTTP request through python

Tags: python, http, networking

I'm working with a programmable attenuator(Electronic instrument) which has been set to a static IP 192.168.1.4 . The instrument provides an interface to set and get values through http post and get over browser . The device is connected locally over ethernet cable.

Ex: http://10.10.10.10/SETATT=115  sets the value to 115
    http://192.168.1.4/ATT?  returns 115.0 , (gets the value)

I need help to send the above get and post request through python3 .
Thanks for any help

```
import urllib.request
wp = urllib.request.urlopen("192.168.1.4/ATT?")
pw = wp.read()
print(pw)
```

I tried this with no luck

Comment: Provide a sample of code that you already tried and the one you are facing problem with.

Comment: I've updated the code that I used , which didn't work.

Comment: Should the /ATT? be the 'text' section of request. I'm not very familiar with http over python.

Comment: What did you expect to happen?  What happened instead?  http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

If http://192.168.1.4/ATT is accessible from your local computer on same ethernet, then use the same URL (http://192.168.1.4/ATT) in the request. Also you didn't mention what response you got from above code. Your webserver on electronic attenuator will also provide information on whether it was able to receive the request or not.